# Don't Repeat Yourself - XAML and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, dry

It turns out that I have exactly the same parts of code in all XAML pages in my application. First piece of code is responsible for transitions:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SlideTransition Mode="SlideLeftFadeIn" />
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
...
```

And the second one describes the application bar:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
...
```

Is there a way which may help to avoid such code duplication? As I understand this cannot be resolved with styles or data templates, or can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation bit can be applied to all pages without code duplication using a Style. Here's the transition style I used for one of my projects. This should be placed in your App.xaml file

```
<Style x:Key="TransitionPageStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
        <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition">
            <Setter.Value>
                <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                        <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
                    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                        <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
                    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can then apply this style to any page you want by inserting this snippet

```
Style="{StaticResource TransitionPageStyle}"
```

to your phone:PhoneApplicationPage tag usually at the very top of any xaml. 
As for the Application bar tag I believe it does need to be repeated as it is sort of like a control itself ie. it has its own properties and methods.

Comment: You can also move some control initialization to codebehind and use the same base class for all pages like here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2011/03/03/creating-a-custom-base-page-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Tariq, I now want to specify my base page method as event handler for application bar button "Click" event. I get XAML parse error related particularly to the event handler. Is it possible to do like so?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some trouble understanding you. What I understand is that you would like to call the same base page method for Click events on multiple pages? This is not possible as event handlers have to be specified in that specific page's code-behind

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought it is possible. Solved with wrappers around base class methods.